# DropDownListFor reports type mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must assign this user a role")]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string UserRole { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult CreateNewUser()
    {
        CreateNewUserModel model = new CreateNewUserModel();
        model.UserRoles = new []
        {
            new SelectListItem{Value="Administrator", Text="Administrator"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="User", Text="User"}
        };
        //model.UserRole = "Administrator";
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UserRole, Model.UserRoles,"Select a role")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.UserRole)
```

When the page to create a new user is loaded, I have got an exception stating that `UserRole must be of type IEnumerable<SelectList>`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
model.UserRoles = new []
    {
        new SelectListItem{Value="Administrator", Text="Administrator"},
        new SelectListItem{Value="User", Text="User"}
    };
```

to:

```
model.UserRoles = List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{Value="Administrator", Text="Administrator"},
        new SelectListItem{Value="User", Text="User"}
    };
```